# How to write a VirtualBox guest driver?

Tags: assembly, virtualbox

I'm running a self-written OS as guest in VirtualBox and in VMware.

I am able to access shared folders in VMware; [this document](https://sites.google.com/site/chitchatvmback/backdoor) describes how to access the VMware host services (such as shared folders).

How can I access shared folders as VirtualBox guest?

Is the API documented at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps try to rephrase your question as a “how do I ...” question instead of a “where is the documentation” question so it's not closed as being off topic.

Comment: @fuz Is it better like this?

Comment: The 5658h port is a well-known para-virtualization mechanism of VMware, VirtualBox uses a PCI device. Luckily, [OSDev already covered it](https://wiki.osdev.org/VirtualBox_Guest_Additions).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks very much. Would you write this as "answer"?

Comment: @MartinRosenau Yes, looking good!

Comment: Specifically, the authoritative documentation appears to be [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Technical_documentation).

Comment: @MartinRosenau I didn't write anything that's worth an answer :) But maybe once you have implemented the driver, you can self answer with your experience (which will provide for an excellent answer!).